# Hibernate with spring aop configuration not updating table data for sql update query

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am using spring(4.2.1) aop transaction management with hibernate(3.6.6 Final).
**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.company.product.datasource.EncryptedDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${db.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${db.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${db.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${db.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">14400</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">1000</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>               
            <value>...</value>  
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="importConfig"
        expression="execution(public * com.company.product.service.impl.ImportServiceImpl.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="importConfig" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="importDao" class="com.company.product.dao.impl.ImportDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="importService" class="com.company.product.service.impl.ImportServiceImpl">
    <property name="importDao" ref="importDao" />
</bean>
```

now when i am call a update query in database it runs without any error and return the no of updated row count but after the end of the transaction if i check the db it is not getting reflected in db. This issue only occur if i use a sql update query.

**Dao code snippet**

```
public void updateIsSubmittableForIncompleteSections(Long documentId, Long supplierId, Set<Long> incompleteResponseDetailIds) {
    Session session = getSession();

    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("update response_details set is_submittable=0 where username_id=:supplierId and response_details_id in (:incompleteResponseDetailIds) and top_level_element_id in (select distinct top_level_element_id from element where document_id=:documentId)");
    query.setLong("documentId", documentId);
    query.setLong("supplierId", supplierId);
    query.setParameterList("incompleteResponseDetailIds", incompleteResponseDetailIds);

    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

appreciate your valuable responses. Thank you.

Comment: First, why didn't you make an entity so that Hibernate will map the database record to?

Comment: it is a legacy application. an i am not allowed to change the mapping. and in this application many places this kind of updates are used. i am just changing the transaction layer of the application. it was initially bean managed transaction of jboss.

Comment: It is always funny to read something like "I have the source code but I am not allowed to fix it" from a software developer. What kind of person is your manager? She wants you to write a stable, maintainable application, does she not? Sorry for having been unable to resist commenting. I am still hoping that someone helps you patch up your legacy code, even though IMO legacy code is more like an extra reason to refactor than a stop sign.

Comment: I am completely agree with you @kriegaex . but as i mentioned in earlier comments, it is a huge application and many places this kind of updates are used and earlier with jboss transaction manager it was working why not with spring. Just for curiosity i want to know what may be the reason.